# How to run a SSIS Package from Visual Studio Environment?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl

I am running SSIS Package (SSDT) from  Visual Studio 2017 Environment, I am getting the error as follows :

> Error: at Data Flow Task, SQL Server Destination [48]: Unable to bulk copy data. You may need to run this package as an administrator.
>   Error: at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SQL Server Destination failed

Per online forum, i ran this file `DTExecUI.exe` to execute the package. I am getting error as follows :-

1. Error: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you
   must install Standard Edition of Integration Services of higher.
2. Task Execute Process Task failed

VS 2017 Professional Edition,SQL 2017 Express Edition (64 Bit)

How to run a SSIS Package from Visual Studio Environment which will allow me to debug?

Comment: Have you tried running VS as an administrator? Note that, as well, that SSDT is for development work. Not for production work; especially when you don't have a licence for SSIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run visual studio with elevated permission (Administrator)

[image]

you need to select `Run as administrator`

Comment: @goofyui why not accepting the answer if it worked??

Comment: Is it asking for Database Administrator or Package admin?

Comment: Any idea why is necessary run it as administrator? in my case i dont have admin privileges on my company pc